# Battery insulating pull tabs for LiPo packs?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, pcb

We are planning to ship devices that contain a small LiPo battery connected to the PCB through a JST connector. Ideally, we'd like the device to be completely powered off until the customer activates it. Also, we'd like to avoid adding an on/off main switch.

I was looking for a PCB component (THT or SMD) that achieves the same thing as battery insulating pull tabs achieve for coin cells or cylindrical batteries (AA, 18650, etc.).

Does something like that exist? So far, I haven't found anything.

Comment: It's called a "battery freshness seal".  Though how do you intend to deactivate the seal/activate the battery?

Comment: I expected to find SMD components that housed some sort of a spring-loaded mechanism. A tab/strap/etc. would be placed between the contacts. The component would sit between the JST connector and the rest of the circuit effectively blocking VCC.

Comment: A simple switch should suffice. It's not hard to design the case so that the switch can only be moved in 1 direction, if that is required.